# Why does my beamer document not show page numbers?

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\small}
\title[]{Slides Template}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ \ }
\begin{center}
\Large 
1. Introduction
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I made the above beamer document. The desired page numbers in the footline are not visible. I wonder what goes wrong there.

Comment: My pdflatex says `\themecolor` is undefined.

Comment: Hey there. Thank you. I got it removed, which does not affect my purpose here. Yeah, now ShareLatex is okay with everything except the page numbers still do not show... :)

Comment: Sorry, but it works fine for me after the edit.

Comment: You dont have any style used yet. This means, there are no headers or footers. Try `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}`.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz This sounds like a good answer -- would you like to convert your comment? BTW: It's enough to write `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]`, the `{}` are not necessary.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: For some themes it is necessary to add `\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}` for it to be visible

Answer (score 4):

By default, beamer does not display any page numbers -- changing their colour or size will not change this. But you can add them to your frames. A convenient way is to use a footline which shows the framenumbers, for example by using `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\title[]{Slides Template}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\Large 
1. Introduction
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]